# Get the Max() value of calculated columns (totals) in a report

Tags: report, rdlc

I am trying to get the value for the column `Max`, which is the max value of columns `A`, `B`, `C`. The rows `T` and `G` are `Total` and `Grand total` (because of row groups), I only need the max value for them :

```
-----------------------------
         A    B    C  | Max   
-----------------------------
      |  1    1    2  |      
-----------------------------
      |  2    1    3  |      
------+---------------+------
   T  |  3    2    5  |  5   
------+---------------+------
      |  2    5    1  |      
-----------------------------
      |  1    2    1  |      
------+---------------+------
   T  |  3    7    2  |  7   
------+---------------+------
   G  |  6    9    7  |  9   
-----------------------------
```

Whenever I try something with the `Max()` function, I get an error like `The expression of [...] uses an aggregate function on a report item. Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in the headers and footers.`.

In MS Excel, I would simply do `MAX(A1:C1)` in column `Max`. Is there any solution to achieve this in rdlc ?

I have search the above error and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700714/1686779), but first option is not possible and second option.. well, I did not really understand it, and I do not think it is applicable for `Max`. If it is, could you explain where I should place the workaround ?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms v10.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to put this code in the field "Max" of the rows "T" and "G".. it should work.. I haven't tryed ;)

```
If Sum(Fields!A.Value) >= Sum(Fields!B.Value) And Sum(Fields!A.Value) >= Sum(Fields!C.Value) Then
    Sum(Fields!A.Value) 
Else if Sum(Fields!B.Value) >= Sum(Fields!A.Value) And Sum(Fields!B.Value) >=  Sum(Fields!C.Value) Then
    Sum(Fields!B.Value) 
Else
    Sum(Fields!C.Value) 
End If
```

> ***update*** after the comment of KevinM

```
IIf ( 
      Sum(Fields!A.Value) >= Sum(Fields!B.Value) And Sum(Fields!A.Value) >= Sum(Fields!C.Value)
      , Sum(Fields!A.Value)
      , ( 
         IIf (Sum(Fields!B.Value) >= Sum(Fields!A.Value) And Sum(Fields!B.Value) >=  Sum(Fields!C.Value)
        ,    Sum(Fields!B.Value)
        , Sum(Fields!C.Value)
      ) 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot have `If` statement in the field expression, only `IIf`, which should work the same, but I have in reality six columns (three here to keep the example simple) and the field expression is really big and unmaintenable...

Comment: This worked with minor changes : 1) I removed the `Sum(...)` because the fields are already calculated, and 2) instead of `Fields!A.Value`, this field reference is made with `ReportItems!A.Value`. Thank you.

Comment: yes your are right.. it is possible to get header values through ReportItems!... .Value. Thank you